# rsync via gateway with ssh and destination connect rsync port (873)

Tags: rsync

```bash
server A --> server B (opened 22 port) --> (firewall) --> server C (opened 873 port)
```

IP

- server B (10.10.10.5)
- server C (10.10.10.6)

  - module name : `dog`

I connect to server B through port 22,
I want to get a file from server B to server C through port 873.

So I wrote the command as below.

```bash
rsync --list-only -e "ssh 10.10.10.5 rsync" 10.10.10.6::dog
```

However, the result was as follows.

```
rsync: did not see server greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1666) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Is it possible to perform rsync with the structure above?

**Server C cannot open port 22, only port 873 is open, and the rsync daemon is running.**